# Does continuity guarantee existence of double integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In single variable real analysis we know if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous then its integral exists over any bounded domain. Does this generalize to the 2-variable case? Does the double integral of a function $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ exist over any bounded domain when the function is continuous, or is uniform continuity (or some other stronger condition) required?

Comment: Continuity in $R^2$ is enough. Because $f$ will be bounded on any bounded subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuity over $R^2$ is good enough for existence of the double integral.